# Create an Array satisfying defined function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Im trying to fill the array to satisfy a condition using `pandas` and `numpy`
I used `import numpy as np` and `import pandas as pd`

```py
X=['e','a','b','c'] #The list of elements to multiply and fill
df=pd.DataFrame([['*','e','a','b','c'],['e','e','a','b','c'],
['a','e','e',np.nan,np.nan],['b','b',np.nan,'e',np.nan],
['c','c',np.nan,np.nan,'e']]) #the array i want to satisfy the next condition
```

and `df` seems like this

```
   0  1    2    3    4
0  *  e    a    b    c
1  e  e    a    b    c
2  a  e    e  NaN  NaN
3  b  e  NaN    e  NaN
4  c  e  NaN  NaN    e
```

```py
def M(R,C): #The Multiplication Function M(R,C)=R*C from the table
    i=X.index(R)+1
    j=X.index(C)+1
    OUT=df[j][i]
    return OUT
```

```py
def condition(Set):
    Condition_satisfication='True'
    for x in Set:
        for y in Set:
            for z in Set:
                if M(x,M(y,z))!=M(x,M(y,M(x,z))):
                    Condition_satisfication='false'
    return Condition_satisfication
```

I need to fill `NaN` entries by an elements from `X` to make the array satisfies the function `condition(Set)`

Comment: Have you looked into the df.fillna() or df.applymap() methods ?

Comment: I have tried `df.fillna` and `numpy.random.choice` but they didn't work!

Comment: Interesting! So the value you want to replace the NaNs with can be any random value from x?

Comment: I just have tried `df.applymap(condition)`, it said there is no `*` in the list `X`, I added it and tried again, then it gave me an Error

Comment: Yes, it should be an elements from the list `X` which make the array satisfies `condition()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple approach using df.applymap()

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X=['e','a','b','c']

df=pd.DataFrame([
['*','e','a','b','c'],
['e','e','a','b','c'],
['a','e','e',np.nan,np.nan],
['b','b',np.nan,'e',np.nan],
['c','c',np.nan,np.nan,'e']
])

# I modified this function to have boolean values as the values of Conditional_satisfaction
def condition(Set):
    Condition_satisfication=True
    for x in Set:
        for y in Set:
            for z in Set:
                if M(x,M(y,z))!=M(x,M(y,M(x,z))):
                    Condition_satisfication=False
    return Condition_satisfication

# Mapping functions passed to df.applymap() go through each value in the 
# dataframe. To access the value you can add an argument to your map function. 
def myMap(val):

    # this if statement checks the value in each cell to see if it's in X
    if val not in X:

        # if it isn't it replaces it with a random value from X
        ind = np.random.randint(0, (len(X) - 1))
        val = X[ind]

    # make sure to return the val to the cell otherwise it defaults to None
    return val

# Apply the map and assign the result to a variable
df = df.applymap(myMap)

# Creating numpy array
array = df.to_numpy()

# Looping through array and checking each row against condition
for row in array:
     if True == condition(row):
        break
```

`condVal` represents the truth value of each row as returned by `condition()`

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, where OP made mistake, and how your answer addresses it. At the very least explain your approach.

Comment: Makes sense! ! I will edit the response to better explain the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. But I still dont know how to make it loops until satisfying the condition `condition()`

Comment: I've edited my response. Let me know if it does what you want!

Comment: I don't know if I clearly understand, but `for row in array` seems to act with one row at each time, right?
I tried it but didn't the whole array didnt satisfy the condition

Comment: could this help ```while True: for row in array: condVal = condition(row) if condition(X)==True: break```

Comment: or this ```while True: df=df.applymap(myMap) if condition(X)==True: print(df) break```

Comment: I went row by row because that didn't return an error from `condition()` so I assumed that was it's intended use. Do you want the loop to stop when `False` is returned by `condition()`?

Comment: Meant to put `True` instead of  `False`

Comment: I edited it to `break` when `condVal == True`

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesn't satisfy `condition()`, when i try `condition(X)`  and it's still giving me `False`